# Regex to Capture Date from below String

Tags: javascript, regex

The below are the sample string which is a combination of `Flight No + Selling Code + Departure Date`.

Flight No have a pattern like `[A-Z]{2}\d{3,5}` and Selling code is single Character. From which I want to capture the Departure date

AA78654UThursday 11 October 2018SI9089UFriday 11 October 2018WW0461XMonday 26 October 2018GF00356ZSunday 26 October 2018

I have tried with Regex but didn't get the expected output

`((?<=[A-Z]{2}\d{3,5}[A-Z, a-z]{1}).*[0-9]{4}((?<=[A-Z]{2}\d{3,5})|$))`

Expected output is : 
**Thursday 11 October 2018

Friday 11 October 2018

Monday 26 October 2018

Sunday 26 October 2018**

Could you please help me to improve the regex to get the departure dates?

Comment: Try `(?:[A-Z]{2}\d{3,5}[A-Z])([A-Za-z]+\s\d{1,2}\s[A-Za-z]+\s\d{4})` and capture the first group

Answer (score 1):

Try something below

```js
window.onload = function()
{

var source = 'AA78654UThursday 11 October 2018'

var regex = /[A-Z]{2}\d{3,5}\w{1}/g

var matches = regex.exec(source)

if (matches)
{
  source = source.replace(matches, "");
  
  console.log(source);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the regex `/.+((?:Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat).+)/`

1. I use a non capturing parentheses to list all possibilities of 3 first letters of each day of week
2. Capture any day of week find from the non capturing parentheses follow by any characters

```js
var chains = [
  "AA78654UThursday 11 October 2018",
  "SI9089UFriday 11 October 2018",
  "WW0461XMonday 26 October 2018",
  "GF00356ZSunday 26 October 2018"
];
var pattern = /.+((?:Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat).+)/
var dates = [];
chains.forEach(function(chain) {
  $matches = chain.match(pattern);
  dates.push($matches[1]);
});

console.log(dates);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `[A-Z]{2}\d{3,5}[A-Z, a-z]{1}(\D*[0-9]{1,2}\D*[0-9]{4})`,

This will match the output you want with the capture group `(\D*[0-9]{1,2}\D*[0-9]{4})`. It will match any number of non digit characters (the day), 1-2 numbers (the day in digits), any non digit again to match the month and 4 digits to match the year.

Answer (score 0):

A regex you can use is **/(Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|Sunday)+.+$#**, however the last part does not contain a capture group. If you also want to capture this part you should wrap the whole regex in parenthesis.

Comment: This does not capture the output which was asked for, thus this regex would not work in the case of this question. It fails to match the last part (after the day)

Comment: Actually it works flawlessly in PHP. The mistake here is that i wrote # instead of / . So you can use this with COPY/PASTE

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for ... in` loop and [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to remove the initial information.

```js
let dateArray = [
  'AA78654UThursday 11 October 2018',
  'SI9089UFriday 11 October 2018',
  'WW0461XMonday 26 October 2018',
  'GF00356ZSunday 26 October 2018'
];

const regex = /[A-Z]{2}\d{3,5}\S/g;

for (let i in dateArray) dateArray[i] = dateArray[i].replace(regex, '');

console.log(dateArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Just Departure Date:

```
(Sunday|Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday)\s([123][0-9])\s(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s(\d{4})
```

Explanation

```
(Sunday|Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday)  // Match Day
\s  // Blank Space after day
([123][0-9])  // Match date
\s  // Blank Space after date
(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)  // Match month
\s  // Blank space after month
(\d{4})  // Match Year
```

Match Whole Thing:

```
([A-Z]{2}\d{3,5})([A-Z])((Sunday|Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday)\s([123][0-9])\s(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s(\d{4}))
```

**Group #1:** Flight Number
**Group #2:** Selling Code
**Group #3:** Complete Departure Date
**Group #4:** Departure Day
**Group #5:** Departure Date
**Group #6:** Departure Month
**Group #7:** Departure Year

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your responses.

With the help of all above response, I have built a regex to get the departure dates as below

`((?<=[A-Z]{2}\d{3,5}[A-Z, a-z]{1})(\D*[0-9]{1,2}\D*[0-9]{4}))`

It is perfectly working.

Thanks for help!!

Comment: Hi! if any of the answers has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this

Answer (score 0):

Poor man's regex.

```
/[A-Z][a-z]+day.+?\d{4}/g
```